# Turning a calculation into a function

Tags: function-construction

I have this chunk of code that I would like to turn into ONE function.  I would like the arguments to be choice and the name of the x-y dataset.

```
choice = "exponential";
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,
   <|"proportional" -> a x,
     "linear" -> a x + b ,
     "quadratic" -> a x^2 + b x + c,
     "cubic" -> a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3,
     "quartic" -> a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4,
     "exponential" -> a Exp[-c x] + b |>[[choice]],
    {a, b, c, d, e}, x];
Print["Equation is ", choice, ": y = ", Normal[nlm]]
Labeled[Show[
  Plot[nlm[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]],  Max[data[[All, 1]]]}], 
  ListPlot[data, 
   PlotStyle -> {Darker@Blue, PointSize[0.02]}]], choice]
```

Comment: Okay, but you haven't explained what part is giving you difficulty. Have you read any of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsAndProgramsOverview.html) on defining functions?

Comment: Yep, I'll go back and read again...I don't know how to combine multiple parts into ONE function, so the nlm part, then the Print and Plot parts.

Comment: essentially put the whole thing in `()` or `Module[]`. You will need a semicolon after the `Print`.

Answer (score 2):

You specification is vague about what you want to give as arguments and what your function should return, if anything. I've made some guesses about those missing specs, so this may not be exactly what you want. However, even so, it should give you ideas on how to proceed.

```
forms = 
  <|"proportional" :> a x, 
    "linear" :> a x + b, 
    "quadratic" :> a x^2 + b x + c, 
    "cubic" :> a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3,
    "quartic" :> a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4, 
    "exponential" :> a Exp[-c x] + b|>;

myFit[data_, choice_] :=
  Module[{min, max, nlm, plot},
    {min, max} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
    nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, forms[choice], {a, b, c, d}, x];
    plot =
      Labeled[
        Show[
          Plot[nlm[x], {x, min, max}],
          ListPlot[data,
            PlotStyle -> {Darker @ Blue, PointSize[0.02]}]], 
        choice];
    Print[Column[{nlm // Normal, plot }]];
    nlm]
```

Now let's how well this does.

```
With[{n = 10}, data = Transpose[{Range[n], Range[n]^2}]];
```

[image: results]

Seems to work well for all the forms except the exponential one. Whether you should adjust the specification of the exponential form or just write it off as not being inappropriate for the data set used, I leave up to you.